# Word VBA: While loop to do until Found nothing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a vba code in ms word that performs a find operation.

It finds a line with specific color. goes to the begining of that line paste from clipboard go to end of the line.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorDarkRed
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

I dont know much coding. just want to perform this find operation until all the lines are found and there is nothing left. Maybe an if or while loop?

Comment: As I said in your other thread on the same topic - which you have now deleted - this can all be done with a basic Find/Replace. No VBA code is required. Moreover, even with VBA, no looping is required. Your recorded macro demonstrates only that you have not correctly implemented the Find/Replace.

Comment: This is not a find replace. This is find and then perform some operations. then find next and perform operations again. Until all are done. If you can help me, Please wrap it into a while or for loop

Comment: and i recorded the macro. But how to loop it?

Comment: Even if a loop were required (which it isn't), there are many examples here of how to do that - I posted one in the last two days on this very page!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy whatever it is you want to replicate to the clipboard, then use an ordinary Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = your font colour
Replace = ^c^&
```

and choose Replace All.

No code required, though you could record it as a macro. No looping required, either.

Comment: Just One More Problem. When I record macro, I set the formatting of replaced text to be bold. But the macro recorder somehow doesn't pick up the part where the replaced text is turned bold. There is no code for that. Is there a way to enter some code to find text with red color and turn it into bold using vba?

Comment: You really shouldn't be changing font properties that way. Both the red and bold attributes should be managed via Style definitions. That said: .Replacement.Font.Bold = True